# Unable to retrieve data from html

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

As for my below code i am not able to get sectionID from tr, i need to get dynamic id of sectionID on each delete button click but it is always giving me null

Here is the Jquery Script :

```
         <script>
      $(function () {
       $('.btnDelete').click(function () {
      var sectionID = $(this).closest('tr').find('.sectionID');
    $.ajax({
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'CheckSectionIDagainststudentID',
        data: JSON.stringify({ sectionID: sectionID.html() }),
        success: function (data) {
            if (data == true) {
                $.alert("Cannot delete | Students exsisting in this 
         Section!");
            }
            else if (data == false) {
                var secCode = JSON.parse(this.data);
                var code = sectionid['sectionid'];
                window.location.href = "SectionDelete?Page=data&sectionid=" 
    + code;
            }
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            $('#result').html(response);
        }
    });
});
        });
      </script>
```

and here is Razor Page

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr class="sectionID">
            <td >
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.sectionID)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name)

            </td>
            <td class="secCode">

                <button style="width:49.5%" ID="Button2" type="button" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("SectionEdit", "Section",new { id = item.sectionID, name = item.name })'">Edit</button>
                <button style="width:49.5%" ID="deletebtn" runat="server" type="button" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("SectionDelete", "Section",new { id = item.sectionID, name = item.name })'">Delete</button>
                <button class="btnDelete">Delete</button>
            </td>

        </tr>
    }
```

This is Controller Which i need to pass data to

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult CheckSectionIDagainststudentID(string sectionID)
        {

            return Json(sectionID);


        }
```

Comment: what i want to do here is using ajax get a the section id from the table and then compare it with the FK of sectionid in student table and if they match it gives an error if they dont match redirect it to the delete method in controller.

Comment: r u getting value in sectionID? at function in string?

Comment: Try this ??  var code = sectionID['sectionID'];

Comment: no it says sectionID : null in debugger

Comment: this does not work wont even direct the debugger to the controller.                            data: JSON.stringify({ sectionID: sectionID.html() }), even here it says null

Comment: r u getting value in var sectionID = $(this).closest('tr').find('.sectionID')??

Comment: no i am not getting any value over here too says sectionID null when my cursor hovers at var sectionID

Comment: can u bind sectionID on <button class="btnDelete" id="modelItem => item.sectionID" onclick=deleteajax(this);>Delete</button> ??

Comment: i did still the value is null :(

Comment: okay it worked i had to change the tr class to sectionID on the button area and it works now thankyou for the help

Comment: ohh wait now its returning me this -->  "\n\n                <button style=\"width:49.5%\" id=\"Button2\" type=\"button\" onclick=\"location.href='/Section/SectionEdit/5?name=Grey'\">Edit</button>\n                <button style=\"width:49.5%\" id=\"deletebtn\" runat=\"server\" type=\"button\" onclick=\"location.href='/Section/SectionDelete/5?name=Grey'\">Delete</button>\n                <button class=\"btnDelete\" id=\"modelItem => item.sectionID\" onclick=\"deleteajax(this);\">Delete</button>\n            "

Comment: and if i use string[] sectionID in the controller method it would return 1 regardless of what row i click delete on

Comment: just bind id on click ? whole? and pass it to parameter?

Comment: i have posted an answer let me know if its work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your question you are not able to get value from var `sectionID = $(this).closest('tr').find('.sectionID');`

therefore here is a way you can achieve your result

```
//Your Dynamic Button should look like this
//in value Bind your sectionID @ MVC
 <button class="btnDelete" value="5" onclick="AjaxDelete(this)">Delete</button>

 //For Function
      function AjaxDelete(values) {
    //Write this in Ajax
    //Fetch Value from attribute value
     var sectionID = $(values).attr("value"); // you will get 5 as value
     //Your Ajax Call with SectionId as Parameter
    }
```

Edit : 
as you have got value 
U can split the value by below code
where string is your var of sectionID

```
 if ((~string.indexOf('\n '))) {
                    string= string.split('\n ')[1].split('\n')[0];
                }
```

Comment: with this change the button wont even work or redirect it to the controller method and i added break points over here too its not even working

Comment: i got it fixed by adding the class to <td> instead of <tr> but now i would get my answer as    \n       1\n    (1 being the id) ... Thankyou for the help

Answer (score 0):

Use string array :

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult CheckSectionIDagainststudentID(string[] sectionID)
        {

            return Json(sectionID);


        }
```

Comment: why do i need a string array when i just need to get just id from that row, plus i did try that still sameerror